# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

I'm trying to hook flask to mongoengine. All modules seem to have been installed succesfully. Here is my import and ln 4 is where the Error is originating:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory
from mongoengine import connect
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine
File "/Users/name/Desktop/venv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py" line 87, in load_module
raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.mongoengine
```

Any ideas of what I may be doing wrong or how I can procure flask.ext.mongoengine?

Comment: Did you install [`flask-mongoengine`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flask-mongoengine/0.7.0)?

Comment: No - I thought that was a separate competing module (sort of like all the different twitter scrapers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install [flask-mongoengine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flask-mongoengine/0.7.0) before you can use it, e.g.,

```
pip install flask-mongoengine
```

This will install a package called `flask_mongoengine`. Until you do that, Flask will have no knowledge about it. That is what causes your `from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine` statement to fail.

`from flask.ext import X` is a convenience inside Flask that will look for packages named `flask_X` (falling back to `flaskext.X` for legacy reasons). If you'd like to learn more about the specifics of the import hook used by Flask, the details are in [exthook.py](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/exthook.py).

Comment: thanks man, that worked. Now i have another error to fix haha.